# MySQL Pivot output in a (new) table or view

Tags: mysql, pivot, group-concat

We store event data into a event database.

I've managed to pivot my tabel in MySQL. To make a graph using MySQL query I need to get the output of the pivot in a table which is auto updated after each new record in a new table or view.

Whats my next step to manage my goal?

My hosting does not allow third party database programs.

The code:

```
SELECT CONCAT(
  'SELECT `view_events`.events_id', 
    GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('
     ,    `t_', REPLACE(JMW, '`', '``'), '`.numParticipants
         AS `', REPLACE(JMW, '`', '``'), '`'
   ) SEPARATOR ''),
 ' FROM `view_events` ', GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('
     LEFT JOIN `view_events`   AS `t_', REPLACE(JMW, '`', '``'), '`
            ON `view_events`.event_id = `t_', REPLACE(JMW, '`', '``'), '`.event_id
           AND `t_', REPLACE(JMW, '`', '``'), '`.JMW = ', QUOTE(JMW)
   ) SEPARATOR ''),
 ' GROUP BY `view_events`.eventname'
) INTO @qry FROM (SELECT DISTINCT JMW FROM `view_events`) t;

PREPARE stmt FROM @qry;
EXECUTE stmt;
```

Comment: Does your query produce different number of fields or fields with different names if new data is added?

Comment: No it does not. Each time a new event is added, the pivot shows a new column based on the date of the event.